# Records affected returns -1 when querying Oracle

Tags: vba, oracle, odbc

I am able to run INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE records to oracle table from excel.
The user has select, insert, update, delete permissions.
But when I try to send simple SELECT SQL I got nothing. CStr(recordsAffected) is [-1]. I need Help on this issue.

```
Private Sub TestB_Click()
Dim recordsAffected As Long

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraDB19Home1};Dbq=ORCL;Uid=cowner;Pwd=pwd;"
Sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLECOD ;"
con.Execute Sql, recordsAffected

If recordsAffected > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Successful!"
    Unload Me
Else
    MsgBox "Not found. Please check values."
End If

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: check whether this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107870/retrieving-data-from-oracle-table-to-excel-using-excel-vba

Comment: Maybe the records affected is not valid in Oracle (for a select)? It’s usually only guaranteed for a DML operation like an UPDATE. Using the returned RS should be preferred for a SELECT.

Comment: A Select returns a record set (e.g. a cursor), so you have to take such records. An INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE returns the **number** or affected records - which is different to a SELECT.

Comment: Have a look at this example how executing a `SELECT` in VBA: https://administrator.de/forum/sql-statement-syntax-oracle-excel-vba-83607.html or https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23717335/Run-Oracle-query-using-Excel-VBA.html